# dotnet format doesn't save output

Tags: c#, .net, format

why is not saved files after use dotnet format? Output seems that everything working good.

```
dotnet format -v diag --files 
D:\_Test\library\Roslyn\RoslynHelper\Format3\A.cs
  Formatting code files in workspace 'D:\_Test\library\Roslyn\RoslynHelper\Format3\Rsp.csproj'.
  Loading workspace.
  Complete in 1098ms.
  Determining formattable files.
  Complete in 585ms.
  Running formatters.
  Formatting code file 'A.cs'.
  Formatting code file 'A.cs'.
  Formatting code file 'A.cs'.
  Complete in 427ms.
  Formatted code file 'A.cs'.
  Formatted 1 of 3 files.
  Format complete in 2222ms.
```

A.cs has content:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i  )        {            
private string _name = args[i]; 
private HttpCookie _cook = new HttpCookie(name, args[i]); 
cook.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);    


 Response.Cookies.Set(cook);        }
```

In file is placed default .editorconfig: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/format/master/.editorconfig

Many thanks

Comment: Could you format your code, please? The second block is difficult to read

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

There are private keywords inside method and "i" instead of "i++" in header of for cycle.

After correct the format is excellent.